# numpy.load() MemoryError while data is just 4.6MB big

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I built a dataset which features lists stored in a numpy array. With some files I get a memory error while still having 8gb left in my RAM. The training file is just 4.5 mb big though and I am trying to append the content to two other lists. I use Python 3.6.7 on Windows 7 and the numpy version is 1.15.4.

[Download this file to recreate the situation (Error Message)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P8ieyM9kNlsiG6LGvwyU0bB7hvQWCjqY)

[Download link for one file which can be opened](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lYNuS8y-X9InQJVVCTA1DMNAoCmmHDE2)

[This file filled up whole RAM](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aq7ZV_QAqMff-xi36kHtbmivCwaxyumr)

```
import numpy as np

test_x=[]

test_y=[]

file= np.load("training_data/6411-0.01848-6-1545931005000.npy")

for d in file:

   test_x.append(np.array(d[0]))

   test_y.append(d[1])


File "D:\Program Files\Halite3_Python3_Windows-AMD64\try.py", line 13, in <module>
file = np.load("training_data/6416-0.02775-6-1545941239000.npy")
File "C:\Users\Fred\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 433, in load
pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Fred\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 657, in read_array
array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
MemoryError
```

Comment: There is no download link. Is it possible that you saved a file improperly? Did you use np.save?

Comment: Just added the download link, I used np.save to save the file.

Comment: I had no problems on Windows 10 running Python 3.7.0, numpy version 1.15.1. This probably has to do with your computer. Please supply os/python/numpy versions.

Comment: I use Python 3.6.7 on Windows 7 and the numpy version is 1.15.4 .

Comment: Okay, that doesn't seem crazy. Looking at your stack trace I notice that you're running a file `D:\Program Files\Halite3_Python3_Windows-AMD64\try.py`, which doesn't appear to be written by you? Try two more things: 1.) try running the script that you posted outside of the context of `try.py` or any other script (i.e. copy and paste what you wrote into a new script and run it); 2.) Try running your original script with task manager open. Check for spikes in memory usage by `try.py` that you might not have anticipated.

Comment: I've written the .npy file but I am developing in the Halite3 folder since I want to participate in the AI competition. When I looked at the task manager I noticed nothing but when I tried it with another not working file my whole memory just got filled up.

Comment: @FredK. When you say "my whole memory just got filled up" you're saying that it appeared as such on task manager? I have no idea why it would happen for one and not the other. Try: 1.) Starting afresh with the data (i.e. download it again or re-compile it)  2.) reinstalling numpy and python. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I just recreated the dataset but still get this issue.